# TYPO3 CKEditor: prevent removal of whitespaces between two HTML tags

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-9.x

I've updated a website from TYPO3 7.6 to 9.5.

Now it seems that the frontend output of CKEditor removes whitespaces between two HTML tags:
`<strong>sometext:</strong><a href="https://domain.tld/" target="_blank" class="external-link-new-window">more text</a>`

In the editor, there is a whitespace between the closing `</strong>` and the opening `<a>` tag.

Is there any way to configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem here is that on version 9.5 the Fluid Content Elements are using the viewhelper `<f:spaceless>` that removes the white spaces - see

```
/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Layouts/Default.html
```

If this is wrong for you you can override the default layout file removing it.

Comment: I would have never imagined that this is the source of my problem. Thx a lot for your help!

Comment: Please note that on the next TYPO3 version (10.x) that placeholder has been removed from the Default.html layout.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this for myself and the RTE deosn't remove the whitespace between `</span> <a href....`.
I Have experienced issues with the CKEditor after uprgading from 7.6 to 9.5 too.
In my case I had to cleanup my TypoScript.

If you have any old configuration in your TypoScript (`RTE.whatever`), remove that and try again.
Maybe you can remove all of your custom TS and check the RTE behavior to make sure the error came from there.

Comment: I removed already almost everything from `RTE.whatever`. But as it turned out, the RTE configuration wasn't the source of my probem (see other answer).